# Same query performance problems when using ORDER BY

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, cte, temporary-tables

I have query that uses a few CTEs. The final output query joins the CTEs together. When I ran the query with no `ORDER BY`, it runs in seconds. When I ran it with an `ORDER BY`, it takes several minutes to return.

I tried the same query with a large number of records. This time, it ran and ran (still running now), even with no `ORDER BY`.

I changed the CTEs to temp tables, and the query ran quickly.

I'm not a DBA and am wondering what type of problem this behavior points to. This query I'm using is part of a stored procedure to be used in an application. Are there any considerations I should think about before making this switch? Thanks.

Comment: can you provide table layouts (keys/indexes only will suffice)?  If you have permissions to display the execution plan that would also help in pinpointing the issue.

Comment: Don't have permission in this database: SHOWPLAN permission denied in database

There are roughly 15 tables in use. I'm hoping a description of the behaviour will point to something that is causing the differences. Also hoping there is no concern with using temp tables in this SP rather than CTEs.

Comment: Please consider reading about [Asking query performance questions](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3034/asking-query-performance-questions)

Comment: Thanks for the link - downvotes without explanation isn't helpful, but your link was!. Thank you. I understand this is an overly-broad question, but hoping someone would be able to help despite my inability to get to more detailed info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you join your CTE with another table, SQL may (depending on the execution plan) execute the code within your CTE multiple time.

Ex : Running this against the stackoverflow database:

```
set statistics io on;

with cte as (
select ID from Users where Location ='Canada'
)
select top 100 title from Posts p 
join cte on cte.Id=p.ParentId


select ID into #user from Users where Location ='Canada'
select top 100 title from Posts p 
join #user u on u.Id=p.ParentId
drop table #user
```

The CTE query made a lot of read on the user table:

```
Table 'Users'. Scan count 0, logical reads 123369, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Posts'. Scan count 1, logical reads 9588, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

The other query with a temp table only read the data once from users so it made way less read (causing the query to be way faster)

```
Table 'Users'. Scan count 1, logical reads 44573, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.

(3687 rows affected)

(1 row affected)

(100 rows affected)
Table 'Workfile'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Worktable'. Scan count 0, logical reads 0, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table 'Posts'. Scan count 1, logical reads 7183, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
Table '#user_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________000000000045'. Scan count 1, logical reads 6, physical reads 0, read-ahead reads 0, lob logical reads 0, lob physical reads 0, lob read-ahead reads 0.
```

Comment: Thank you. I went with the temp table option.